# Calculate the distance between $AC$ and $BD$ in the regular tetrahedron $ABCD$.

Tags: geometry, volume, angle

**Question**

Consider the regular tetrahedron $ABCD$. The points $M$ and $P$ are the means of the segments $BC$ and $AM$, respectively. On the edge $BD$ take the point $K$ so that $BK = 3*KD$ Knowing that the distance between the lines $PK$ and $AC$ is $\sqrt{3}$ cm, calculate the distance between $AC$ and $BD$.

**My idea**

**Drawing **

[image: drawing]

I know that most of these types of problems are solved using the volumes expressed in two ways.

So we can easily show that $AC \perp BD$, which makes the angle between these two lines $90$ degrees.

We can use Chasles Formula(I explained it in the comments) and we get that the volume of the regular tetrahedron is $= \frac{AC*BD* dis(AC, BD)*sin(90)}{6}$.

We can say that because we have a regular tetrahedron $AC=BD$ and we also know that $sin(90)=1$

If we can express the volume again using the given distance we can find the distance between $AC$ and $BD$.

I don't know where to start! I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Note that the vertices of a regular tetrahedron are half of the vertices of a cube, such that the tet's edges are diagonals of the cube's faces. Thus, the distance between opposite tet edges is the distance between opposite cube faces; ie, the cube's own edge-length (which is easily related to the tet's edge-length).

Comment: @Blue Ok, but how is this going to help solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: *"how is this going to help solve this problem?"* That's a different question. :)

Comment: Hint: Via triangle $BPK$, calculate the side length of the regular tetrahedron. As you already know the ratio between $BP$ and $BK$, as well as $\angle PBK$

Comment: @LeoJi Thanks for your hint. The information makes me think of a possible similarity of triangles. Let $x$ be the side of the tet. . I calculated $BP=\frac{3x\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $BQ=3x$, which will make their ratio $\frac{BP}{BQ}=\frac{\sqrt{2}} {2}$. I don't know which other traingle I should have chosen.

Comment: @LeoJi Seems finding $\angle PBK$ is not trivial.

Comment: Can you use coordinate geometry?

Comment: @dfnu Thanks, but sorry im not udes with coordinate geometry. Is there any way to transform it in a solution without coordinate geometry?

Comment: I would look anyway for the plane parallel to $PK$ through $AC$... Maybe its intersection with $BD$?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Let $A'ABC$ be a tetrahedron in which $A'A
= a, BC = b$,
distance between $A'A$
and $BC$ is $c$, and the measure of the angle between $A'A$
and $BC$
is $u$.
Then the volume of the tetrahedron $A'ABC =\frac{a*b*c*sin(u)}{6}$.

I can easily demonstrate it for you if you want.

Comment: The proof is not a problem, but I couldn't find a reference to this theoreme online. Can you provide some link where this name "Chasles Formula" is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note first of all that
$$
volume(KPAC)={1\over4}volume(KBAC)={3\over16}volume(ABCD).
$$
Hence, from the formula given in the question we get:
$$
PK\cdot AC\cdot distance(PK,AC)\sin\alpha={3\over16}AB\cdot CD\cdot distance(AB,CD),
$$
where $\alpha$ is the angle between lines $PK$ and $AC$,
that is:
$$
distance(AB,CD)=
{16\over3}{PK\over CD}\cdot distance(PK,AC)\sin\alpha
={16\over\sqrt3}\ {PK\over CD}\sin\alpha.
$$
To evaluate $PK/CD$ and $\alpha$, draw from $P$ and $K$ two lines parallel to $BC$, intersecting edges $AC$ and $CD$ respectively at $E$ and $F$ (see figure below). Observe that $PE={1\over4}BC=KF$, hence $PEFK$ is a parallelogram. As a consequence, $PK=EF$ and $\alpha=\angle CEF$.

From the sine rule in triangle $CEF$ we then get:
$$
{PK\over CD}\sin\alpha={EF\over CD}\sin(\angle CEF)=
{CF\over CD}\sin 60°={3\sqrt3\over8}.
$$
Inserting that into the above formula we finally get:
$$
distance(AB,CD)=6.
$$

[image]